# Using SSO alfresco automatically logged in LIferay Portal

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, alfresco

how to use SSO in liferay portal if alfresco it is been integrated ?
Meanwhile i have to login in liferay portal and again login in alfresco portlet and alfresco it is been integrated in liferay portal ??

[Image of Alfresco_Liferay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh5Bd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco in the Cloud has SAML integration that can use an SSO identity provider.
There is an enterprise SAML module for on-premise coming soon, or you can pay for consulting to get it earlier.  Otherwise, perhaps you can do something with Alfresco External Authentication, and hook into an SSO solution that way.
See http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/auth-intro.html

Comment: Yeah ahmed already a assign a new user in alfresco although i can able to login in liferay by screen name . see my liferay login is bruno bruno and alfresco portlet username and pwd is bruno bruno now i want to use SSO here. Any idea about this??