# AUTO login alfresco

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, alfresco, cas, alfresco-share

I have integrated alfresco in liferay.
Also i am using the third party that is CAS.

Now the questions comes when i clicked on sign in button then it goes to cas login page , now when i put the username and password then it login but the alfresco that i had integrated it is not logged in.
kindle tell me how do i put the authentication so that once i login with cas automatically it should also login.

How can i auto login of alfresco in liferay?

Comment: Isn't it a duplicate with this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687824/using-sso-alfresco-automatically-logged-in-liferay-portal

Comment: yeah it is but i am thinking to do with auto login also ??

Answer (score 0):

Check your CAS log files, it will clearly give you the details like after CAS login whether is called your alfresco or not, if not chech your client implementation in alfresco.

Comment: No sir it is not called .

Comment: In your client application check the CAS implementation once, else share with me the piece of code i will suggest you.